# Problem with Listening gRPC Requests Over HTTP on Cloud Run

Tags: grpc, google-cloud-run

I was running my gRPC services on Cloud Run without any problem. But today, I realized they are no longer working over HTTP including the services that have no change for a long time.

The exception is `The request :scheme header 'https' does not match the transport scheme 'http'."`

So, is there any change on Cloud Run side or is there anything that I am missing?

Update: If I change the code to receive requests over HTTPS, probably they will work(not tested yet). But, it is not the point. They were running without any issue before.

Update2: I implemented the Program.cs and the docker file as explained on there https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/c-sharp and this is not working too.

Update3: Same with that sample project. https://github.com/turgayozgur/dotnet-hello-world-grpc The sample application isn't expecting HTTPS on :scheme header. Why cloud run set that header as HTTPS even the request between Cloud Run and application is not an HTTPS request?

Similar issues:
https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd/issues/2401
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/dotnet/aspnetcore/30532/787011248

Answer (score 2):

You have to set in Kestrel options

> options.AllowAlternateSchemes = true

You can find details here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.allowalternateschemes?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround that worked for me:

1. Download the aspnetcore repo, I use v5 so `git clone https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore.git && cd aspnetcore && git checkout tags/v5.0.5`
2. Find the file `/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http2/Http2Stream.cs` and comment out lines 244-250.  If not version 5.0.5, it's the block of code that starts with `if (!ReferenceEquals(headerScheme, Scheme) &&`, comment that whole if block
3. build the project - `./build.sh --configuration Release` in the root of the project.  It had a few errors but the file I needed was built.
4. Take file `aspnetcore/artifacts/bin/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Release/net5.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll` and copy it to a folder with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

COPY ./Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/5.0.5/
```

A bit of a pain, but we're back up on Cloud Run with this ...

Comment: Luckily, I was using Cloud Run for a test environment. I can't imagine I am on the production. I think Cloud Run is risky on production. I hope they start to make some tests on major languages before any change.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: check wlhe’s comment, it seems there is a bug in aspnetcore that broke this. Reverting the version can help.

Applications serving on Cloud Run has to serve unencrypted HTTP traffic (and in grpc case since it uses http2, this is called "h2c"). Do not try to terminate TLS in your application, because you won't be getting any encrypted requests.

Encryption is terminated/added by the infrastructure and your service does not see it.

---

To get a sample C# gRPC application working on Cloud Run.

1. clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc repository
2. go to `grpc/examples/csharp/RouteGuide`
3. update /RouteGuide.csproj like this

   ```
   -    <Protobuf Include="..\..\..\protos\route_guide.proto" Link="protos\route_guide.proto" />
   +    <Protobuf Include="protos\route_guide.proto" />
   ```
4. go into `RouteGuideServer`
5. change the program to listen on PORT env var or 8080, also on all interfaces (e.g. * or 0.0.0.0). and delete that weird interactive read from terminal prompt:

```
diff --git a/examples/csharp/RouteGuide/RouteGuideServer/Program.cs b/examples/csharp/RouteGuide/RouteGuideServer/Program.cs
index dff6486e59..a32aff7222 100644
--- a/examples/csharp/RouteGuide/RouteGuideServer/Program.cs
+++ b/examples/csharp/RouteGuide/RouteGuideServer/Program.cs
@@ -17,6 +17,7 @@ using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
+using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
 namespace Routeguide
@@ -25,22 +26,18 @@ namespace Routeguide
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
-            const int Port = 30052;
+            const int Port = 8080;
 
             var features = RouteGuideUtil.LoadFeatures();
 
             Server server = new Server
             {
                 Services = { RouteGuide.BindService(new RouteGuideImpl(features)) },
-                Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
+                Ports = { new ServerPort("*", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
             };
             server.Start();
 
-            Console.WriteLine("RouteGuide server listening on port " + Port);
-            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
-            Console.ReadKey();
-
-            server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
+            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
         }
     }
 }
```

5. `gcloud beta run deploy routeguide --source=. --allow-unauthenticated`
6. Your gRPC service is now publicly available and listening on URL:443.

Comment: Thank you for the details but that is what I am currently doing. I am not trying to terminate TLS in my application. As I understand, the exception message saying the request coming over the HTTS. Sure, the message might be hiding some other exception. I will keep working on it and getting a simple example to reproduce it.

`The exception is The request :scheme header 'https' does not match the transport scheme 'http'."`

Comment: Same with that sample project. https://github.com/turgayozgur/dotnet-hello-world-grpc
The sample application isn't expecting HTTPS on :scheme header. Why cloud run set that header as HTTPS even the request between Cloud Run and application is not an HTTPS request?

Similar issue: https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd/issues/2401

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30532

Comment: I wrote this example of using envoy as mitigation: https://github.com/Frank-Schmutz/CloudRunDotNetGRPCService/pull/1/files